# How to parse url params from a URL with respect to route match path

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-router-dom

How do I parse any given url string with respect to `match.path`?

For example if the current route I am on is:

`<Route path="/some/path/:type" />`
I'd simply use match.params.type to get the `type` param of the current url. But what if I have some arbitrary URL string, `const url = "/some/path/foo"`, is there a way I can parse this with respect to `match.path`?

I'm using `react-router@5`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "with respect to `match.path`"? Is there an issue or problem you have accessing the route path params?

Comment: I mean, with respect to `"/some/path/:type"` - i'd like to be able to parse any given url string and extract the `:type`, not just the current URL.

Comment: So you want to take some arbitrary string and extract the route path params manually?

Comment: @DrewReese yes 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`matchPath`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/matchPath) utility to manually match a path string to a specified path. It returns a [`match`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/match) object if there's a match, or `null` otherwise.

Example:

```
import { matchPath } from 'react-router';

const url = "/some/path/foo";
const path = "/some/path/:type";

const match = matchPath(url, { path });

console.log(match?.params.type); // "foo"
```